# When to use quotes in command line? cp versus find

Tags: command-line, terminal, quotes, double-quotes, cp

I'm wondering if there is some pattern or trick to remember when or when not to use quotes in command line arguments.

e.g. what is the difference between:

```
find -type f -name "*<extension-with-quotes>"
```

and

```
cp <extension-without-quotes> ../<new-folder>
```

One needs quotes and one does not, else it gives an error.  Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes if you don't want the ***shell*** expanding the arguments, but instead want the argument passed through verbatim to whatever program you're trying to run. See, for example, the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf ("Argument count = %d\n", argc);
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf ("   %2d: [%s]\n", i, argv[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs its argument count and arguments. The following transcript shows how it runs with and without quotes:

```
$ ./testprog "*.sh"
Argument count = 2
    0: [./testprog]
    1: [*.sh]

$ ./testprog *.sh
Argument count = 7
    0: [./testprog]
    1: [xmit.sh]
    2: [gen.sh]
    3: [morph.sh]
    4: [prog.sh]
    5: [mon.sh]
    6: [test.sh]
```

---

So, for example, if you're in a directory with three log files, the shell will change your:

```
ls *.log
```

into:

```
ls a.log b.log c.log
```

*before* handing that list on to the `ls` program (the `ls` program will never *see* the `*.log` at all).

However, `find` expects a file ***pattern*** rather than a list of files, so it will ***want*** the `*.log` passed through as is, one single argument rather than three individual arguments expanded by the shell.

In fact, if you had only `a.log` in the current directory, an unquoted `*.log` would *only* find files called `a.log` regardless of how many other log files existed in the directories below. That's because `find` never saw the `*.log`, only the `a.log` that the shell expanded it to.

---

A similar example is with `expr`. If you want to know what three times seven is, you *don't* want to be doing:

```
expr 3 * 7
```

since the shell will first expand `*` into all the files in the current directory:

```
3 dallas_buyers_club.avi nsa_agent_list.txt whitehouse_bomb.odt 7
```

and `expr` won't be able to make much sense of that<sup>1</sup>. The correct way of doing it is along the lines of:

```
expr 3 '*' 7
```

in effect preserving the `*` so the program gets it unchanged.

---

<sup>1</sup> Special note to the NSA, CIA, MPAA and other dark shadowy organisations formed to strike fear into the hearts of mortal men. That file list is ***fictional humour.*** I really *don't* want any men in dark suits showing up at my front door :-)